# Convert MATLAB sum function with ~= not equal condition to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I want to convert this `sum(sum(W_set{1}~=0))` into Python:

```matlab
%MATLAB code:
W_set = {[[[-0.05747274, -0.05268928],
         [-0.10961724,  0.10119643],
         [-0.0327577 ,  0.01514941]]],
      
         [[[-0.05557293,  0.11311244],
         [-0.22935626, -0.11837874],
         [-0.05567432, -0.0558801 ]]]};

sum(sum(W_set{1}~=0))
```

The output is 6. how can I get this output in Python, `W_set` in Python is a list.

I have tried the following approach, but the result is not the same.

```py
#Python code:
import numpy as np
W_set = [[[[-0.05747274, -0.05268928],
         [-0.10961724,  0.10119643],
         [-0.0327577 ,  0.01514941]]],
      
         [[[-0.05557293,  0.11311244],
         [-0.22935626, -0.11837874],
         [-0.05567432, -0.0558801 ]]]]

if np.array(W_set[0]).all != 0:    #checking not equal to zero
  sum_ = np.sum(np.sum(W_set[0]))  #sum
print(sum_)
```

The answer is -0.13619112. What is the meaning of operator `~=` when used in the MATLAB `sum` function?

Comment: In Matlab: `W_set{1}~=0` returns an array with the same size as `W_set{1}` but that only contains 1s and 0s depending if the element in the same position in the original array is not zero. So, `sum(sum(W_set{1}~=0))` is basically just counting the number of non-zero elements in your original array.

Comment: Great! for curiosity, the `W_set{1}~=0` in Matlab return 1s. When will it return 0 because I have negative elements `W_set{1}`

Comment: It will return 0 only if the starting element is exactly 0. Negative elements are, as you might guess, not zero, so they also return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.sum` it will sum over all the axis, but in order to compare the elements to zero in a vectorized instruction you need it to be a numpy array

```py
np.sum(np.array(W_set[0]) != 0)
```

Alternatively you could have made `W_set = np.array([...])` and then

```py
np.sum(W_set[0] != 0)
```

```py
(W_set[0] != 0).sum()
```